# MySQL & PHP, mysqli_num_rows always returns 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little problem with a basic register script that im writing and i cant seem to be able to fix it.

Well, here is the code:

```
<?php

//MySQLi connection

$con = mysqli_connect("-","-","-","users");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())

{

echo "MySQLi Connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();

}

//Reading the userdata from the registerp.php page

$usr = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);

$pass_unhashed = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);

$pass = password_hash($pass_unhashed, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

//Checking if user exists

$check_usr = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT FROM users WHERE user_name = $usr");

if (mysqli_num_rows($con,$check_usr)>=1)
{
echo "This Username already exists";
}
else
{
echo "This Username is available";
}

?>
```

Problem is that i cant get the verification (so that people cant register the same name twice) to work:

```
$check_usr = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT FROM users WHERE user_name = $usr");

if (mysqli_num_rows($con,$check_usr)>=1)
    {
    echo "This Username already exists";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "This Username is available";
    }
```

Always returns "This Username is available", even though the User i used to test it with (nevondrax), is in the MySQL table (thats how it looks like [click](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1469005298.png)
)

Comment: Can i move it to there somehow?

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stacsuperuser.com.com/help/how-to-ask). You can flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: You need to verity manually that `mysqli_query()` succeeds, mysqli won't do it for you. Once you do,you'll notice the SQL parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query (`SELECT FROM users WHERE user_name = $usr`) doesn't select any lines so there are no lines returned, hence `mysqli_num_rows` is always zero.

In addition you're also missing some quotes around your parameter. Right now your query would look like this:
`SELECT FROM users WHERE user_name = dummy`

Correct would/should be:
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = 'dummy'`

If we take your code block and adjust it, it might look like this:

```
$check_usr = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name = '$usr'");
if($check_usr === false)
{
    echo(mysqli_error($con));
}
else
{
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check_usr)>=1)
    {
        echo "This Username already exists";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "This Username is available";
    }
}
```

Comment: So i would have to query ( SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = $usr) ?

Comment: it's    SELECT usr FROM users WHERE user_name = $usr

Comment: Sorry for not including the correction. What @devodedra wrote is correct. You need to include some kind of field or an asterisk to select every available field.

So it would be either `SELECT field FROM table` or `SELECT * FROM table`.

Comment: Hrm, i just tried to use the asterisk and also the field name, but the result is still the same. Could the error be in my register page? (The html page)

http://pastebin.com/hhaFfu5R

Comment: In addition you are/were missing some quotes around the username. I edited my answer accordingly. Using `mysqli_error($con)` report it as well as an invalid query.

Comment: I now have everything just like you did up there, also tried to mess around with a few other things, but nothing seems to work... i also dont get a error message...

Comment: You probably should check that your PHP is set to actually report errors (check out `error_reporting(E_ALL)`). It doesn't look like it is. You can try by making the query invalid on purpose. There were two more errors I didn't catch which are fixed in my answer (now). The first is that `mysqli_num_rows` only takes a single parameter and the second that I missed the `$` where it said `if(check_usr === false)`.

Comment: Solved! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Your syntaxt of select query is wrong.**

```
$check_usr = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT FROM users WHERE user_name = $usr");
```

you have to write syntax as

```
$check_usr = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT fieldname FROM users WHERE user_name = $usr");
```

*you missed to give field name after SELECT*